# can rest server be launched inside the hyperledger/composer-playground container?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

Can rest server  be launched inside the hyperledger/composer-playground container? Want to know ways to interface with business network inside the play ground

I get following error when I try to install composer-rest-server

Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.  + hyperledger composer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible to install composer-rest-server inside a container created from the hyperledger/composer-playground image. Docker containers are really only meant to execute a single process. Although it is possible to run multiple processes within a docker container it isn't the way docker containers should be used.
If your playground is connecting to a real fabric, then you can use the composer-rest-server docker image to create a container to connect to that fabric and access your business network or you can run the composer-rest-server as a normal process. If you are only using the web browser profile in playground to develop your business network then it isn't possible for the composer-rest-server or any composer client to access that business network as it is executed and stored inside your browser.

Comment: Thanks David. So if I have to create a POC that interfaced with business network then I need to have development tools installed which is only possible in Ubuntu or Mac. Please let me know if there is way I can install dev tools on windows. Thanks again.

Comment: Windows is not officially supported but can be made to work. However the easiest way is to use a hypervisor such as virtualbox and run Ubuntu in a virtual machine.